# Painting nine squares to swing not working?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am trying to add 9 squares of different colors using java, this is what I am doing:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class GUI{
  private JFrame frame;
  private ArrayList<Blocks> squares;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();    
  }

  public GUI(){
    frame = new JFrame("Blocks");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    squares = new ArrayList<Blocks>();
    squares.add(new Blocks(100,200,150,20,10));
    squares.add(new Blocks(120,100,50,100,10));
    squares.add(new Blocks(70,255,0,180,10));
    squares.add(new Blocks(150,150,150,20,70));
    squares.add(new Blocks(100,100,100,100,70));
    squares.add(new Blocks(0,0,0,180,70));
    squares.add(new Blocks(220,200,50,20,130));
    squares.add(new Blocks(110,80,150,100,130));
    squares.add(new Blocks(90,235,195,180,130));

    frame.setBounds(850,300,300,260);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout());
    for(int i = 0; i<squares.size(); i++){
      frame.add(squares.get(i));
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);    
  }
}

class Blocks extends JComponent{  
   private JLabel label;
   private int r;
   private int g;
   private int b;
   private int x;
   private int y;

   public Blocks(int r,int g,int b, int x, int y){
     super();          
     this.r = r;
     this.g = g;
     this.b = b;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
 //label = new JLabel(s);
 //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 //add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 //setLocation(20,10);
 //setSize(80,60);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics G){
     super.paintComponent(G);
     G.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
     G.fillRect(x,y,80,60);
   }
}
```

So only one square is showing, but when I expand the frame, all squares are shown but there is huge gaps between them, I am trying to make them next to each other as you can see by my x and y values, I would like to have all of them next to each other in a 300*260 frame, each square is 80*60.

**EDIT**
All components ARE showing, not only one is showing, but they are showing when I expand the frame only and they are far apart not next to each other as I want them which I thought would work. Not duplicate.

Comment: You're likely drawing off the screen. Understand that for each block, the 0,0 position is at the top left corner of the **block** not of the **JFrame**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing custom painting from (x, y) of the component. You should be doing the painting from (0, 0) of the component.

You are using the layout manager to position the component in a grid, so you just let the layout manager determine the (x, y) location of each component and then you just fill the component. based on its size.

You should also be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of the component so that the layout manager can determine the initial size of the component when pack is used.

> I want a gap between the frame and the components, they are filling the entire frame

Use an EmptyBorder on the parent panel.  Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

change the paintComponent():

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics G) {
    super.paintComponent(G);
    G.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
    G.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

If you want they have gaps:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics G) {
    super.paintComponent(G);
    G.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
    G.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() * 9 / 10, getHeight() * 9 / 10);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, how can i add gaps around them? Not between, so they are now one big square (which is what i want), but I want a gap between all of them and the frame

Comment: @Abdane, I gave you this advice and more 8 minutes earlier. This doesn't explain, what the problem is. Any answer should explain the problem and give a solution. Also the solution for the gaps is not the best solution. Again, a component should be responsible for painting itself. If you need gaps between the components, you use the appropriate layout manager, or property of the layout manager.

Comment: no no, I want a gap between the frame and the components, they are filling the entire frame

Comment: @camickr I think you're not fair, your answer just explains the x, y should be zero, but not resolve the problem with width & height. And how do you overide the getPreferSize(), I really want to know. And you said the gaps should be controlled by layout manager, so how can set the gap between components with GridLayout?

Comment: @Abdane, I know you reject my answer, but if you only read his answer, how can you know width & height value?

Comment: People reading the answer should not have to go line by line comparing the original code to see what the difference is. So, the point of an answer is to explain the problem, not just dump code. So my answer explains that the OP's understand of custom painting is wrong, that you need to do the painting relative to the component, not the frame. Whether the OP wants to paint the component at a fixed size, (which is what they currently are doing), or whether they want the want the component to grow/shrink based on the size is up to the OP.

Comment: `And how do you overide the getPreferSize(),` - you read the API to determine what the method returns and then return the value you desire. Again, we are not here to write the complete code, only give the OP the information needed to solve the problem. The OP can easily search the forum for examples that override the `getPreferredSize()` method if they are unsure how to do it. This is called learning by example.